# Sending URL inside another URL

Tags: python-3.x, url, python-requests, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

So I'm building a telegram bot with python and I need to send to the user an URL. I'm using telegram send_text URL:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&parse_mode=Markdown&text={message}`

but the URL that I'm using:

`https://www.amazon.es/RASPBERRY-Placa-Modelo-SDRAM-1822096/dp/B07TC2BK1X/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=YJ6X8FN3V801&keywords=raspberry+pi+4&qid=1577853490&sprefix=raspberr%2Caps%2C195&sr=8-3`

has a special character like `&` that prevents the message to be sent with the full URL. In the case of this URL I only receive this:

`https://www.amazon.es/RASPBERRY-Placa-Modelo-SDRAM-1822096/dp/B07TC2BK1X/ref=sr13?mkesES=ÅMÅŽÕÑ`

I tried using utf-8 to replace the characters like `&` but python transforms them back to "real character" so I had to throw the idea off. 
In case you want to check out what I tried here is the code snippet:

`url = url.replace('&', u"\x26")`

So is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at [`urllib.parse.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the URL with [urlencode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

```py
import requests
import urllib.parse

link = "https://www.amazon.es/RASPBERRY-Placa-Modelo-SDRAM-1822096/dp/B07TC2BK1X/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=YJ6X8FN3V801&keywords=raspberry+pi+4&qid=1577853490&sprefix=raspberr%2Caps%2C195&sr=8-3"
markdownMsg = "[Click me!](" + urllib.parse.quote(link) + ")"
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=<ID>&text=" + markdownMsg + "&parse_mode=MarkDown"

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers={}, data ={})
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

This also works for `&parse_mode=HTML`

```
htmlMsg = "<a href=\"" + urllib.parse.quote(link) + "\">Click me!</a>"
```